# Save struct model with dereferencing

Tags: go, struct

I have this struct for user

```
type User struct {
    gorm.Model
    Username  string        `gorm:"not null;unique" json:"username"`
    Password  *string       `gorm:"not null"json:"password,omitempty"`
    Email     string        `gorm:"not null;unique"json:"email"`
    Addresses *[]UserAddress `json:"addresses,omitempty"`
}
```

When I bind json to my struct I can save password to the database like this

```
userObj := User{}
password := *userObj.Password
userObj.Password = &password
db.Debug().Save(&userObj)
```

The part that is not working is when I try to apply the same thing for Addresses field. Error from terminal is this "field value not valid".

Here's the playground [link](https://play.golang.org/p/ZICMwVDUSm)

Comment: Could you post the code you use specifically for `userObj.Addresses`?  It might help to know exactly what is causing the problem rather than leaving it up to our imagination.

Comment: Please show a complete example. The code here can't be valid, as you're immediately dereferencing a nil pointer.

Comment: @JimB I've added playground link with my structs, it's everything but validation function there

Comment: Even with the playground link, it doesn't look complete. there is no declared User.Mobile in the struct. You're not checking if Username, Password, and Email is not null, you're using the `not null` attribute, which would definitely be invalid if one of these fields is null. Also, why are you persisting pointers to the DB rather than the value? Does GORM implicitly store the value rather than the pointer?

Comment: Are you sure you want a pointer to a slice of UserAddress (`*[]UserAddress`) rather than a slice of pointers to UserAddress (`[]*UserAddress`)?